# PRESTASHOP: How to tell PDO class to connect through a socket instead of 'localhost'?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prestashop

In Prestashop 1.6.1 in the /classes/db/DbPDO.php in the function _getPDO I see that the PDO the dsn connection string is built conditionally. In particular the following snippet is of interest:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:';
if ($dbname)
        $dsn .= 'dbname='.$dbname.';';
if (preg_match('/^(.*):([0-9]+)$/', $host, $matches))
        $dsn .= 'host='.$matches[1].';port='.$matches[2];
elseif (preg_match('#^.*:(/.*)$#', $host, $matches))
        $dsn .= 'unix_socket='.$matches[1];
else
        $dsn .= 'host='.$host;
```

So, what is it expecting to see in the $host in order to set the connection type to unix_socket?

I imagine it's looking at the _DB_SERVER_ variable in the settings.inc.php. Is that right?
Currently I have it set to 'localhost'. What would I need to change it to so that PDO connects using a socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock?

Thank you for any suggestions,
Raine

Comment: Try to use `unix:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` as your db host. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, Gustavo, your suggestion does work, as explained by bishop below. You should have posted a proper answer to be awarded the bounty. I'm awarding the bounty to bishop as he provided a more exhaustive answer (and not just a comment), but I do appreciate your response to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the code, this appears to be the trick:

```
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'unix:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock');
```

What comes before the colon is irrelevant.  The important thing is the string start at the beginning of a line, have a literal colon then slash (`":/"`), and everything thereafter is the absolute path to the socket file.  This pattern, therefore, requires an absolute path to the socket.

The `_DB_SERVER_` constant appears to be the canonical way to configure PrestaShop's database based on the docs.

Comment: Thank you, @bishop. I suspected that the string before the colon was irrelevant but was confused why would the socket path have a colon in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've get it.
But firstly you must locate the mysql unix socket file path. Usually it is in my.cnf mysql config (in my Debian: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`). Then search `socket` entry under `[client]`. So:

```
# see my.cnf under [client]
$unix_socket = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'; 
$user   = 'user';
$passwd = 'secret';
$dsn = 'mysql:unix_socket=' . $unix_socket . ';dbname=dbname';

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $passwd);
```

Well, note When the host name is set to "localhost", then the connection to the server is made thru a domain socket by default.